# Jquery .click not working when changing css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html,

```
<h2 class="more-button">Read More</h2>
```

and am trying to have it change the position of another div when it is clicked. To accomplish this I am using

```
$(".more-button").click(function(){
    $(".hidden-block").css("right", "110%");
});
```

**FIDDLE :** https://jsfiddle.net/wfxxkk3x/

But the code does absolutely nothing. I have tried many different approaches with this problem and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your css classes along with proper html. And better create a Fiddle

Comment: @Manish Here is a fiddle of what I am working with https://jsfiddle.net/wfxxkk3x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector of the `hidden-block` from a class to an id

```
$(".more-button").click(function(){
$("#hidden-block").css("right", "110%");});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wfxxkk3x/5/

or use animate to animate the div

https://jsfiddle.net/cjon7apg/

Comment: Thank you this is just what I was looking for. I must've put it in as a class by accident.

Comment: a simple mistake,better luck next time

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine with your code .. In your js fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/wfxxkk3x/ . **You have "hidden-block" as an ID not a Class .**

So just change your jquery selector to "#" hash .

**Example :**

```
    $(".more-button").click(function(){

//hidden-block is an id
    $("#hidden-block").css("right", "110%");

});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What CSS do you have set on your `<div class="hidden-block"></div>`? Because if you haven't set positioning anywhere, then your `"right", "110%"` will do nothing.

Try setting `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` on your `.hidden-block` and that should allow you to move the block around.

If you don't have a stylesheet and you want to go pure jQuery then something like this:

```
$(".more-button").click(function(){
  $(".hidden-block").css({"position":"relative", "right":"110%"});
});
```

Comment: I have the positioning set to absolute, but the button still seems to do nothing on click

Comment: The  code for the hidden-block is `#hidden-block {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 18%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-13deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-13deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(-13deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-13deg);
    transform: skewX(-13deg);
}`

Comment: Ah... you should be using #hidden-block rather than .hidden-block because hidden-block is the ID

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `position` of the div in order for it to be affected by `right`

```
position: relative;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the position of the div is already set to absolute. Here is a jsfiddle to show what I am working with https://jsfiddle.net/wfxxkk3x/

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, i notice "hidden-block" is ID not CSS, so your javascript must be:

```
$("#hidden-block").css("right", "110%");
```

Then, do you include jQuery? In your fiddle, i didn't notice jQuery library in External Resources.

After changing . to #, and add jQuery, your code works correctly. Try changing 110% to another value and see the result.